# Internet Explorer Loading Gif Problem (lazy-swiper)?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, lazy-loading, swiper.js

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtXFk.png)

I'm trying to close/hide Internet Explorer image loading gif. Another browsers not showing like this. I'm using Swiper and Lazy libraries. It's not appear in libraries or inspect html/css tags. How can I disable this animate/gif?

Comment: show us your code pls.

Comment: Do you mean you are using the Swiper and Lazy libraries to display the loading image? Can you post enough code or [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we could reproduce the problem and narrow down the issue.